# Test class for pagereference in a method

Tags: apex, unit-test, pagereference, salesforce-classic

I am unable to get code coverage for my pagreference, my code is

code:

```
public class selectedcase {
public list<recordtype> record {get; set;}
public id ids;        
public selectedcase(){
 record =[select id, name from recordtype where sobjecttype='case'];
}

public pagereference submit(){
ids = system.currentpagereference().getparameters().get('rid');
if(ids == null){
apexpages.message newmsg = new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.error,'Please select atleast one recordtype');
apexpages.addmessage(newmsg);
return null;
}
else{


pagereference newpage = new pagereference('/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo&RecordType='+ids+'&ent=Case');
newpage.setredirect(true);
return newpage;
}
```

And test class is

```
@istest

public class selectedcasetest {
    public static testmethod void testselect(){
    selectedcase selnew = new selectedcase();

     recordtype rec = new recordtype();
        rec.Name ='testname';
        rec.SobjectType='case';

        pagereference pager = page.recordtypes;
        test.setCurrentPage(pager);
        system.currentpagereference().getparameters().put('Recordtypeid', rec.Id);
        system.assertEquals(rec.Id, rec.Id, 'Please select atleast one recordtype');
        selnew.submit();
        }
    }
```

Please help. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to query case recordtype if you are passing recordtype id as url parameter.

Comment: Hi Reshma, I just gave a try to use it but it didnot work, after the else part I am unable do code coverage.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Unit testing questions are very common here, so the community has set up a few questions under the [tag:canonical-qa] tag to address the most common issues. Please give those a look and see if they help you out.

Comment: You need to test your code using different data setup to exercise both logic paths. Please see the linked question for more information and resources.